# Sort varchar with letters and numbers - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, varchar, natural-sort

I have a database with records in varchar I want to order. Currently, I use the following query to sort by numbers:

```
SELECT name
FROM table
ORDER BY 
NULLIF(regexp_replace(name, E'\\D', '', 'g'), '')::int
```

Mixed records (numbers + letters) are ordered correctly, but records with only letters are not properly sorted:

```
Query Results:
name:
1st guy
2nd guy
3rd guy
10th guy
11th guy
v guy
a guy
z guy
c guy
```

While the result I want is:

```
Query Results:
name:
1st guy
2nd guy
3rd guy
10th guy
11th guy
a guy
c guy
v guy
z guy
```

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values that have no numbers all result in a NULL value for the `ORDER BY`. The order of those rows is undefined as they all have the same "value" to be sorted by. You need to add the `name` column as a second sort criteria. You probably also want to make sure that the NULL values from the first expression are sorted at the end:

```
ORDER BY NULLIF(regexp_replace(name, E'\\D', '', 'g'), '')::int NULLS LAST, name
```